# How can I pass custom data into a MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback?

Tags: swift, macos, core-audio

I am successfully using an MTAudioProcessingTap in Swift on MacOS to manipulate my audio routing for both live playback and export. However, the specific routing that should occur at runtime depends on the user's choices. What I would like to be able to do is pass in a pair of Ints to the MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback when I create the tap so that I can use a single callback definition that can use those Ints to determine how to do the routing. The problem is that the callback is a C function pointer that can't capture context.

I thought maybe I could use the clientInfo parameter of the MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks to hold the values I need, but I can't find any documentation on how I can access this parameter from within the MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback.

I have 32 possible routing combinations, and unfortunately the only other option I see at this point is declaring 32 separate MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallbacks, and then selecting which to use when I create the tap. But it would be so much easier for me if I could just have a single MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback that makes a simple decision based on passed-in data.

Comment: If passing data ever becomes too burdensome, consider using a singleton object in your app (if you don't already have one) that can facilitate data transfer. I've run into situations where two objects needed to share data but were so far apart that it was more economical for me to simply create a singleton that the first object updated that the second object read from. When your user taps, the first object updates the singleton with the integer values before communicating with the second object and so the second object always knows that those values are available to read from after each tap.

Comment: (comment con't) That said, subclassing should usually be your first attempt. If you can subclass the object and inject your own custom properties, I'd probably do that. I've never worked with `MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback` so I can't say but I assume you've explored that option.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how it works. In order to access the data inside the clientInfo from within the Process callback:

1. Inside the MTAudioProcessingTapInitCallback you have to initialize the tapStorageOut with the clientInfo pointer
2. Inside the Process callback use MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap) to get that pointer and access the data.